# nested tables from json object using anguarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Im trying to display a json object using angular. the object may have nested object or not, so i need to evaluate in runtime.
The logic is as follows :
for each key-val (k,v):
   if v is an object then: for each (k2,v2) add another nested table in the HTML_TD. if not - need to print the value in a HTML_TD

The nested object works. 
The problem : when v is an object i expect the expression to evaluates to '' and print nothing (because im going to an inner loop k2,v2) but instead, even if v is an object, it print it out to the HTML_TD

code :

```
<table border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in json.properties">
    <td> {{ k }} </td>
    <td> {{ typeof (v) == 'object' ? '' : v }} </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v">
                <td> {{ k2 }} </td>
                <td> {{ v2 }} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` function is not defined on angularjs template interpolation, the template syntax is a bit limited in terms of javascript functions but you can declare it on your scope like so:

```
$scope.typeof = function(obj) {
    return typeof(obj);
};
```

So that a function named `typeof` will be visible on your scope and your snipet will be able to get working. The bellow snipet is a simple example implementing this solution.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.json = {
      properties: {
        a: 'A',
        b: 'B',
        c: {
          a1: 'A1'
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.typeof = function(obj) {
      return typeof(obj);
    };

  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in json.properties">
      <td>{{ k }}</td>
      <td>{{ typeof(v) == 'object' ? '' : v }}</td>
      <td>
        <table border="1">
          <tr ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v">
            <td>{{ k2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ v2 }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ! - i define a new method $scope.is_object() and is now reachable from html/angular code.

Answer (score 0):

I think angular parser don't allow `typeof` function in template.
But you can define one method in controller to get `typeof`.
E.g.:

```
$scope.getTypeof = function(value) {
        return typeof value;
};
```

Now call this method in template code:

```
{{ getTypeof(v) === 'object' ? '' : v }}
```